# Snippet of code not working

Tags: javascript

Below is a simplified snippet of code from a form validation script. It does not work...

When the form is submitted and the user has left "inputfield" empty, the first alert pops up. After the user has entered something in "inputfield", the second alert pops up when the user clicks submit.

Afterwards, the script should return false and continue validation. I need both alerts to be included in the same else if. What am I doing wrong? The alerts do not show and the form validation ignores this portion of code...

```
    } else if (myform.inputfield.value=="") {
    alert ('Please enter something in the text field!');
    }
    if (myform.inputfield.value!=="") {
    alert ('Thank you for entering something in the field!');
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling the code? Also, you should probably nowadays use `document.getElementById`to find the field.

Comment: Did you try replacing "" with NULL or  removing return false?

Comment: first try to do a console.log(myform.inputfield.value) when the textbox contains a value and when it doesnt, i'm sure you will get a null value. Then like Peitu said, use document.getElementById. this is 2014 ;)

Comment: Calling the code with <form onsubmit="return validate(this)". Will work on all other sugestions, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it better to declare a flag and return the it as a result? take the following sample into account:

```
var validationResult = true;

...
} else if (myform.inputfield.value=="") {
   validationResult = false;
   alert ('Please enter something in the text field!');
}
if (myform.inputfield.value!=="") {
   alert ('Thank you for entering something in the field!');
   validationResult = false;
}

return validationResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree rather use document.getElementById, or jQuery $('#input1').val()

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('input1').value == "") {
            alert('Please enter something in the text field!');
        }
        if (document.getElementById('input2') !== "") {
            alert('Thank you for entering something in the field!');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return validate()">
        <input id="input1" />
        <input id="input2" />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </form>
</body>
```

You might have a return statement before the specified line of code?

Comment: I have a return false;

Comment: If you have return false; before the alert validation, the alert validation will not be reached.

Comment: It is reached, but ignores "Please enter something in the text field!" and jumps to "Thank you for entering something in the field!"... Argh!

Comment: okay, what does this line preduce when adding it to the top of you validation code alert(myform.inputfield.value)

Comment: also note that your "Please enter something in the text field!" is in a else if, if the first statement is satisfied the else if will be skipped.

Comment: ... produces an empty alert

Comment: also note that your "Please enter something in the text field!" is in a **else if**, if the first statement is satisfied the **else if** will be skipped